# OpenLayers - "polygon.getLayout is not a function" while creating a MultiPolygon

Tags: openlayers, well-known-text

I'm having trouble creating a WKT. The point of the code is to get the current map extent and send it to the server in a WKT format.

Here's the code :

```
let format = new WKT();

// get map extent
let currentExtent=this.map.getView().calculateExtent(this.map.getSize());

let test = new MultiPolygon([currentExtent[0],currentExtent[1],currentExtent[2],currentExtent[3]]);
// I tried with let test = new MultiPolygon(currentExtent) but it does'nt work either

const feature = format.writeGeometry(test, {
      dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
      featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857',
    });
```

and here's the error :

> ROR TypeError: polygon.getLayout is not a function at new MultiPolygon
> (MultiPolygon.js:92:1)

The error occurs when I try create a new MutliPolygon to intialize the 'test' variable.

The project uses Angular and Spring frameworks but I'm not sure that's relevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An extent is simply the bottom left and top right coordinates of a rectangle
A polygon is one or more closed rings of coordinates pairs for each of the vertices - i.e. the 4 corners plus the starting point repeated to close the ring.  A further pair of [] is needed to make a MultiPolygon from Polygon coordinates

```
[[[
  [currentExtent[0],currentExtent[1]],
  [currentExtent[0],currentExtent[3]],
  [currentExtent[2],currentExtent[3]],
  [currentExtent[2],currentExtent[1]],
  [currentExtent[0],currentExtent[1]],
]]]
```

Comment: It worked, thanks Mike !